# Free CAPTCHA plugin for WordPress

Tags: gratis, wordpress, spam, captcha

I started a WordPress blog a while ago and for the past month or so, I have been the target of comment spam.

The most obvious solution? Use CAPTCHA against bots.

Google has recently updated its CAPTCHA (the tick in the box). Is there such a plugin I can integrate with WordPress comments?

Comment: Captcha's are obtrusive. Look into finding a honeypot solution. Another solution could be using something like Akismet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Wordpress plugin Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) by BestWebSoft

https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/screenshots/

In the settings you get to choose the captcha version. (the tick in the box would be version 2).

**Example:**

[image]